# Go programming language slice from end

Tags: go, slice

In python you can use the following syntax as a shortcut:

```
a[-1]    # last item in the array
a[-2:]   # last two items in the array
a[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
```

Does Go have shortcuts similar to the second and third example when creating new slices?

Comment: See [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) on a full list of available expressions. What you want is not possible.

Comment: @nemo that is helpful thank you!

Comment: This is also a great [resource](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you have to use `len(a)`.

```
a[len(a)-1]
a[len(a)-2:]
a[:len(a)-2]
```